Windows 11 - Command Line Path - Microsoft Office 365, Edge, Chrome, FireFox
On my previous work issued laptops I have been able to use the Run prompt box or Command Line Prompt to launch Microsoft Office applications, Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox using single word commands such as:

winword
excel
msaccess
outlook
powerpnt
msedge
chrome
firefox

However, on my newly issued Microsoft Surface Studio Laptop 2, those command are no longer working as expected and I am getting 'msaccess is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' type errors.
I suspect that there needs to be a setting set, however, I do not know what they would be, and my previously issued laptop is not available for me to look up the settings.
Could someone please assist with the settings needed to set up?
Thank you

This question is similar to: Open MS Access from the Command line. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see On-Topic. Please talk to your IT department.
